# How do i send a DM to a user using discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I've put a silly bot together that will join a voice channel when prompted and play a clip of Gordon Ramsay. The voice feature works great after some trial and error. Currently I'm trying to have it DM a list of the mp3's available to play but I'm running into an error. I think my if statement to DM the user is interacting with my logic to play a random mp3 in voice channel. I'm still quite new to this.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.member.voice.channel && message.content === `${prefix}list`) {
    message.author.send('placeholder');
}
if (message.member.voice.channel && message.content === `${prefix}gordon`) {
    const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    const dispatcher = connection.play(mp3[Math.floor(Math.random() * mp3.length)]);
    dispatcher.on('start', () => {
        console.log('Audio is now playing!\n Deleting command in chat.');
        message.delete();
    });
    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Audio has finished playing!');
        connection.disconnect();
    });
    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
}});
```

It successfully sends the DM but it has errors.

````
```(node:14168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of null
at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\index.js:53:20)
at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\Havok\Desktop\GordonBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage
````

```
(node:14168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14168) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the bot receives a DM message, `message.member` will be `null` (because it can't be a guild member; it wasn't sent in a guild).

Check if the message was sent in a guild first before attempting use `message.member.voice` or playing music:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    // rest of code...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

dm user

> message.user.send("msg");

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.member.voice.channel && message.content === `${prefix}list`) {
messsge.user.send("Message");
}
})
```